# Bouncing 30 balls around the screen

Tags: python, class

My assignment is to display 30 bouncing balls onto the window created. I've only started learning about classes, and I can't seem to figure out a loop on how to display 30 balls to bounce. I'm able to bounce one ball off of all four walls.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

# Dorthy Petrick
# Display 30 bouncing balls bouncing around the screen

from graphics import *
from time import sleep
from random import *

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dx = 1
        self.dy = 1

    def draw(self, win):
        self.ball = Circle(Point(25, 60), 3)
        self.ball.setFill('blue')
        self.ball.draw(win)

    def move(self):
        self.ball.move(self.dx,self.dy)

        xValue = self.ball.getCenter().getX()
        yValue = self.ball.getCenter().getY()

        if 550 < xValue:
            self.dx = -self.dx

        if -xValue > xValue:
            self.dx = -self.dx

        if 500 < yValue:
            self.dy = -self.dy

        if -yValue > yValue:
            self.dy = -self.dy

def main():
    win = GraphWin("bouncy.py", 550, 500)
    ball = Ball()
    ball.draw(win)
    counters = []

    while True:
        for i in range(30):
            ball.move()
            counter = Counter()
            counter.setCounterId(i + 1)
            balls.append(ball)



    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you are appending the same `ball` each time to `balls`. you need to initiate a new `Ball()` object each time you do your for-loop.

Comment: On the code review side : 
- Try not hardcoding values like screen width (pass those as parameters or declare them as global variables).
- Avoid at all costs the `from X import *`, your main function is kind of useless (shifts the declaration for no reason other than C similarity)
- Your `sleep(0.05)` inside `ball.move()` will be problematic later (the more ball to move the more sleep time !), think about moving it in the main event loop. Have fun :)

Comment: Also, indentation problem in your `Counter.__init__`. Consider posting the successful code on the CodeReview site =)

Comment: I'm not sure what `Counter` is for! :P

Comment: That  too. I just realised also that **regardless of `ball.x`, your draw function draws in the same place : (25, 60)**

Comment: @Jiby , How would I change the Point to a random range of points?

Answer (score 4):

Considering your ball class is ok:

> Edit to fix your Ball class:

```
import random
class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dx = 1
        self.dy = 1
        self.ball = Circle(Point(random.randint(0, 550), random.randint(0, 500)), 3) # use random to randomly display the balls
        self.ball.setFill('blue')

    def draw(self, win):
        self.ball.draw(win)

    def move(self):
        self.ball.move(self.dx,self.dy)
        #sleep(0.005) #not needed...

        xValue = self.ball.getCenter().getX()
        yValue = self.ball.getCenter().getY()

        if 550 < xValue:
            self.dx = -self.dx

        if -xValue > xValue:
            self.dx = -self.dx

        if 500 < yValue:
            self.dy = -self.dy

    if -yValue > yValue:
        self.dy = -self.dy

def main():
    win = GraphWin("bouncy.py", 550, 500)
    ball_lst = [Ball() for i in range(30)] #Initialize 30 balls
    for ball in ball_lst:
        ball.draw(win)
    while True:
        for ball in ball_lst: # for each ball in our balls list
            ball.move() #move the ball
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```

This should do the job.

Comment: I seemed to be getting an AttributeError due to 'Ball' object has no attribute 'ball'.

Comment: @Dorthy you create `self.ball` inside `Ball.draw`, so when you try to call it in `Ball.move` it doesn't exist yet. Try moving that to the `__init__` method instead.

Comment: Im currently getting a larger error about the graphics. line 396, in draw
    if self.canvas and not self.canvas.isClosed(): raise GraphicsError(OBJ_ALREADY_DRAWN)
graphics.GraphicsError: Object currently drawn

Comment: @Dorthy, try this last one, it seems that draw method should be called just once, anyway, care about that all the balls are being instantiated with the same values, so each of them are one upon the other

Comment: @DanielSanchez any tips on how to create random points for the circles?

Comment: @DanielSanchez when I use the randint function for the point i get a builtin_function_or_method error that objects has no attribute 'randint'